# Select parent if all children meet criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tables set up like so:

```
Parent
------
id, ...

Child
-----
id, parent_id, x, y
```

I want to find the Parents, or the distinct parent_id(s), if *all* of the rows in Child containing a given parent_id meet a criteria involving x and y(in my case x = y).

For example:

```
Parent
------
id
 1
 2
 3

Child
id, parent_id, x, y
1,      1,     2, 3
2,      1,     3, 4
3,      2,     5, 5
4,      2,     6, 7
5,      3,     8, 8
6,      3,     9, 9
```

would result in 3.  Currently, I have a query that finds parent_ids that *any* of the children meet the criteria.  I then use that to retrieve those records and check them in code if all the children meet the criteria.  With the example data, I get parent_id 2 and 3, get the two parent records with all children, and evaluate.  I want to do this with a single query, if possible.

Comment: can you pls tell what is ur expected output?

Comment: @AnandPhadke, my expected output would be 3.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, MS SQL Server.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012? Do you have multiple levels of parent/child or just that single level as shown in your example data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, 2008 R2.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, there are actually multiple levels, but there is a view that condenses it to the two.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT id 
FROM Parent p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM Child c
   WHERE c.parent_Id = p.id
   AND c.x <> c.y
)
```

Edit: Here's the sql-fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20128/1/0

Comment: I had a similar case, I needed get all parents but in a column show who meet the criteria in children. I use a LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 1 as a, p2.id FROM Parent p2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Child c2
        WHERE c2.parent_Id = p2.id AND c2.test = 'f'
    ) AND 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Child c2
        WHERE c2.parent_Id = p2.id AND c2.test = 't'
    )
) cOK ON cOK.id = p.id

Comment: Isn't there any way to achieve this without a subquery? Looks low performing on large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need?

```
  select id from parent where id not in(
    select parent_id from child 
    where x<>y
    group by parent_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should join 2 tables first because the parents does not have children that will satisfy

And should add index for pa_id column

```
SELECT DISTINCT pa.id 
FROM pa INNER JOIN c ON c.pa_id = pa.id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM c WHERE c.parent_Id = p.id and c.x <> c.y )
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I think it worth to give my 5 cents on this topic. I believe more efficient way is to use HAVING clause:

```
SELECT 
   Parent.id
FROM
   Parent 
   JOIN Child ON Child.parent_id = Parent.id
GROUP BY
   Parent.id
HAVING
   SUM( CASE WHEN Child.x = Child.y THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT( * )
```