# Rails 4 scope through status on related objects?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope

I'd like to eliminate an instance method in a rails scope I've written, so I can have a better, chainable scope.

I've got a model `Offering` that `has_many :assets`, and `Assets` have a column `status`. I've created a scope on `Offering` that looks like this:

```
scope :available, -> { where(approved_for_sale: true).reject{|offering| !offering.assets_ready} }
```

where `assets_ready` is a method on `Offering`:

```
def assets_ready
  assets.inject(1) {|memo, asset| memo && asset.ready_status_symbol == :ready}
end
```

Since reject returns an array, I'd like to find a way to write the scope that doesn't require the instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :available, -> { 
                      where(approved_for_sale: true)
                      .where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from assets a WHERE 
                        a.offering_id = offerings.id AND a.ready_status <> 'ready')")
                     }
```

Solution inspired by Tim's answer to a SQL question here: [Select parent if all children meet criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075068/select-parent-if-all-children-meet-criteria)

Market's answer will work for some use cases, but the group clause introduce some weird behaviors with chaining and count; e.g. Offering.available.count will return a hash instead of a fixnum if the available scope uses .group

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a chainable scope you must use methods from `ActiveRecord` query api.

Assuming `status` column type is string, I think you need something like:

```
scope :available, -> {
    where("offerings.approved_for_sale = ?", true).
    joins("INNER JOIN assets AS all_as ON all_as.offering_id = offerings.id
         LEFT JOIN assets AS ready_as ON ready_as.id = all_as.id AND ready_as.status = 'ready'").
    group("all_as.offering_id").
    having("COUNT(all_as.id) = COUNT(ready_as.id)")
}
```

It returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`instead of an `Array`.

Comment: This seems to return an offering if _any_ of the assets has status: :ready, rather than _all_. Otherwise, a good start.